# cannot create a user in the postgresql databae using prisma in next js

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma

I have been following a youtube tutorial trying to create a chat app.

i have implemented firebase authentication to give users a signing up process.

I am using prisma and postqresql as my database. the login page is working properly and once i login it authenticates with google and proceeds me to the onboard page where i choose the required fields and as i click the " create new Profile " i get an internal 500 error referring to the onboard-user api route and console logging shows me the error occurs while created the user.

here is the code

AuthController.js

```
import getPrismaInstance from "../utils/PrismaClient.js";

export const checkUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email } = req.body;
    if (!email) {
      return res.json({ msg: "Email is required.", status: false });
    }

    const prisma = getPrismaInstance();
    const user = await prisma?.user?.findUnique({ where: { email } });
    if (!user) {
      return res.json({ msg: "User not found", status: false });
    } else {
      return res.json({ msg: "User Found", status: true, data: user });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

export const onBoardUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, name, about, image: profilePicture } = req.body;
    if (!email || !name || !profilePicture) {
      return res.send("Name Email and Image are required.");
    }
    const prisma = getPrismaInstance();
    const user = await prisma.user.create({
      data: { email, name, about, profilePicture },
    });
    console.log("User created:", user);
    return res.json({ msg: "Success", status: true, user });
  } catch (err) {
    next("Error creating user:", err.message);
  }
};
```

onboarding.jsx

```
import Avatar from "@/components/common/Avatar";
import Input from "@/components/common/Input";
import { useStateProvider } from "@/context/StateContext";
import { ONBOARD_USER_ROUTE } from "@/utils/ApiRoutes";
import axios from "axios";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function onboarding() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [{ userInfo, newUser }, dispatch] = useStateProvider();
  const [name, setName] = useState(userInfo?.name || "");
  const [about, setAbout] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState("/default_avatar.png");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!newUser && !userInfo?.email) router.push("/login");
    else if (!newUser && userInfo?.email) router.push("/");
  }, [newUser, userInfo, router]);

  const onboardUserHandler = async () => {
    if (validateDetails()) {
      const email = userInfo.email;
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(ONBOARD_USER_ROUTE, {
          email,
          name,
          about,
          image,
        });
        if (data.status) {
          dispatch({
            type: reducerCases.SET_NEW_USER,
            newUser: false,
          });
          dispatch({
            type: reducerCases.SET_USER_INFO,
            userInfo: {
              id: data.user.id,
              name,
              email,
              profileImage: image,
              status: about,
            },
          });

          router.push("/");
        }
      } catch (err) {}
    }
  };

  const validateDetails = () => {
    if (name.length < 3) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
  return (
    <div className="bg-panel-header-background h-screen w-screen text-white flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center gap-2">
        <Image src="/whatsapp.gif" alt="whatsapp" height={300} width={300} />
        <span className="text-7xl">PakChat</span>
      </div>
      <h2 className="text-2xl">Create your profile</h2>
      <div className="flex gap-6 mt-6">
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-6 mt-5">
          <Input name="Display Name" state={name} setState={setName} label />
          <Input name="About" state={about} setState={setAbout} label />
          <div className="flex items-center justify center">
            <button
              className="flex items-center justify-center gap-7 bg-search-input-container-background p-4 rounded-lg"
              onClick={onboardUserHandler}
            >
              Create Profile
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Avatar type="xl" image={image} setImage={setImage} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default onboarding;
```

scheema.prisma

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  email String @unique
  name String
  profilePicture String @default("")
  about String @default("")
}
```

prismaClient.js

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

let prismaInstance = null;

function getPrismaInstance() {
  if (!getPrismaInstance) {
    prismaInstance = new PrismaClient();
  }

  return prismaInstance;
}

export default getPrismaInstance;
```

I have the database up and running to does show the Pakchat db created with the schema tables also generated. it is just when i try to create the user i see nothing generated int he db hence nothing shows up in the prisma studio either. what i doing wrong i would really appreciate the help. I am following a youtube tutorial and somehow it works for them but i keep getting this error of no user being created. where am i going wrong?